# is is possible to move/copy an s3 bucket to a different account?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Does Amazon provide a way to copy a bucket from one account to a different account? I am uploading several gb of files to my own bucket for a client app for development purposes, but when handing off the code I'm going to want to switch the bucket to their account (so I am no longer paying for the storage).  Uploading is taking quite awhile because there are many small files, and I would like to avoid the same arduous process later, when I move the files into the other bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use crossftp ( http://www.crossftp.com/ ) to server transfer it from one account to another. But you will still have to pay the traffic.

other solution would be: http://gallery.bucketexplorer.com/displayimage-93.html

Comment: thanks.  I guess they don't have the api call that I want.  I found that you can do a "copy" from one bucket to another but you still have to list the files, there's not bulk copy (that I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

[boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/index.html) works well. According to the creator of boto:

> Assuming you have account A and account B and all of the objects are
>   currently stored in a bucket owned by account A, you should be able to
>   grant account B read access to the existing bucket(s) and then, using
>   the account B credentials COPY the objects into a bucket(s) owned by
>   account B. I think something like this should work:

```
 conn = S3Connection(...) source_bucket =
 conn.lookup(source_bucket_name) dest_bucket =
 conn.lookup(dest_bucket_name) source_key =
 source_bucket.lookup(key_name) dest_key = source_key.copy(dest_bucket,
 key_name, preserve_acl=True)
```

> This would create a key of the same name in the destination bucket and
>   would also preserve the source key's ACL and metadata.